# Fuseki 2 initial setup

Tags: fuseki

I can’t figure out what the basic initial/minimal setup of Fuseki is if I want something like Bob DuCharme in his Learning SPARQL book. He uses old release of Fuseki (0.2.6) and starts it in a very trivial way (with no additional configuration):

```
fuseki-server --update --loc=dataDir /myDataset
```

With **only** this he has a fully functional SPARQL endpoint with a default graph. However, neither with Fuseki 1 nor Fuseki 2 I am able to do this. With Fuseki 2 the server runs immediately but the UI does not react—I can’t upload or edit, it shows no datasets (I would expect it should list `/myDataset` at least!). It works only like a purely static page with no functionality on the background.

The console log looks like everything works:

```
 fuseki-server --update --loc=dataDir /myDataset
 [2015-11-11 09:05:05] Server     INFO  Fuseki 2.3.0  2015-07-25T17:11:28+0000
 [2015-11-11 09:05:05] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_HOME=/home/honza/.apache-jena-fuseki-2.3.0
 [2015-11-11 09:05:05] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_BASE=/home/honza/karolinum/run
 [2015-11-11 09:05:05] Servlet    INFO  Initializing Shiro environment
 [2015-11-11 09:05:05] Config     INFO  Shiro file: file:///home/honza/karolinum/run/shiro.ini
 [2015-11-11 09:05:05] Config     INFO  Template file: templates/config-tdb-dir
 [2015-11-11 09:05:05] Config     INFO  TDB dataset: directory=dataDir
 [2015-11-11 09:05:10] Config     INFO  Register: /myDataset
 [2015-11-11 09:05:10] Server     INFO  Started 2015/11/11 09:05:10 CET on port 3030
```

Comment: It really seems the problem could be in running Fuseki on a virtualhost. When I am testing the same on a local computer, everything runs very smoothly. On the virtualhost even the --mem does not help.

Comment: I have just tried to change the routes (via redbird) from my virtualhost’s IP to it’s localhost but it didn’t work either.

Comment: see http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/Apache_Jena#Script_to_start_Fuseki_server for a solution as of 2020-09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The solution is it is necessary to change security settings in `run/shiro.ini` file, like this:

```
[users]
username=password

[urls]
## Control functions open to anyone
/$/status = anon
/$/ping   = anon
/$/** = authcBasic,user[username]
# Everything else
/**=anon
```